# mysql & php select * query not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table in my db called sales. Each row has a value in the column federal.
So I want to collect all federals in an array within this code, but it just doesn't work and I dont know why... Please help! Thanks!

```
  <?php
              $db = mysqli_connect("server", "usr", "pw", "db");

              $FederalRes = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `sales` WHERE `state` = 'Österreich'"); //gets every row with the state = 'Österreich'

              $federals = array(); // empty array to collect federals

              while ($row = $FederalRes->fetch_object()) {
                if (!in_array($row->federal, $federals)) { // check if federal is already in array
                  array_push($federals, $row->federal); // adds federal to array
                }
              }

              sort($federals); // sorts the array alphabetically

              foreach ($federals as $key => $value): ?>
                <li><?php echo $value ?></li>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: does the connect work? are you getting a connection with the db? what's the error? please provide more info

Comment: Ups.. Forgot 'echo' in the li element

Comment: What does not work?

Comment: You might want to use `$federals` instead of `$variable` in your foreach loop.

Comment: The connection works fine and I get no error.. just 0 rows as respond from the query

Comment: When I check the db in phpmyadmin I see that there are many rows where state = Österreich

Comment: wait, what does the table look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try with the `LIKE` statement instead of `=`.

Please try with the below code:

```
<?php
  $db = mysqli_connect("server", "usr", "pw", "db");

  $FederalRes = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `sales` WHERE `state` LIKE 'Österreich'"); //gets every row with the state = 'Österreich'

  $federals = array(); // empty array to collect federals

  while ($row = $FederalRes->fetch_object()) {
    if (!in_array($row->federal, $federals)) { // check if federal is already in array
      array_push($federals, $row->federal); // adds federal to array
    }
  }

  sort($federals); // sorts the array alphabetically

  foreach ($federals as $key => $value): ?>
    <li><?php echo $value ?></li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: oh thanks you very much! I dont't know why but it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
try{
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'root',     '');
}

catch(Exception $e){
die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}

$answer= $conn->query("SELECT * FROM sales WHERE state LIKE 'Österreich' ORDER BY state ASC"); //sort it alphabetically here ;)


while ($data = $answer->fetch()){
    echo $data['federal'] . '<br />';
}
$reponse->closeCursor();

?>
```